# Bet with Ax3x3x on river?

Tags: betting-strategy, cash-game, nl200

From the small blind on a 1-2nl cash game, hero calls ($1) with Ax3x. About half the table has called so there is about $10 in the pot. Everyone checks on the flop and turn. The river is a 3x so now hero has Ax3x3x. Everyone checks. Hero gets surprised reactions for checking with the best hand. But it seems to me there were so many possible better hands but this was a table with some very loose players. Should I have bet on the river?

Edit: forgot to mention this was final table with 4 players. I don't recall the exact board, other than there were no 2s.

Comment: Too few details. What's your position ? What was the flop and the turn ?

Comment: Position already given - small blind. Flop and turn were junk cards like 7x9x but this is implied since they did not help hero or apparently anyone else. It just seemed to me that if anyone paired with anything higher than a 3 on the board I was behind. And the way this table was playing if I bet I might have been raised with a weak but better pair or even with a bluff.

Comment: There really needs to be clear info about the flop texture before anyone can make a reasonable judgement on what is the best course of action.

Comment: Without table VPIP/PFR/Stack-size and without the community cards it's impmossible to give advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you had A3s (suited) and not A3o (offsuit). A3o is definitely a fold pre.

You didn't tell us what the rest of the board was, but yes it is most likely extremely standard for you to check the river here. A bet won't likely get value from worse hands, and almost all better hands will call.

Comment: No. Ax3x indicates offsuit which I agree is normally a fold, but what I failed to mention that this was the final table with only 4 players left, so to me, any A is good.

Comment: you said it was cash...

Answer (score 2):

Betting is never good here. By betting into 3+ players OOP it's very strong on the river, your range is only strong hands. You're getting called by a hand that dominates you and getting folds from worse hands. I.E. there is only negative value in betting in all realistic possible states of the world. Check fold would be best against most opponents and board textures here. Unless you're playing creative opponent on the button and the board is extremely dry.